# how do we know if a beizer curve generated by 3 points is not part of hyperbola?

Tags: solution-verification

sure the path traced by the two points look parabolic in shape but isn't that foolish to just assume it is parabolic with out actual proof? i am hoping if some one can give me a decent explanation of why that path is parabola but not part of hyperbola or some curve. any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you can construct a parabola with three distinct points. You cannot construct a hyperbola, for which you would need 5 distinct points, or a cubic polynomial, for which you would need 4 distinct points. A parabola might not actually be the best fit for the correlation but it is the polynomial of highest degree that you can construct using just three data points. he quadratic in this case is a function that will go to each of the data points implying that the curve of best fit will have zero error in regards to the data collected.